# How to repeat a message to console using a schedule

Tags: scala, zio

I am trying to learn how schedules work, and I just want to display a simple message to the console using a schedule.

```
import zio.console._
import zio._
import scala.util.Try
import zio.duration._
import zio.clock._

object MyApp extends zio.App {

  def run(args: List[String]) =
    myAppLogic.exitCode

  val myAppLogic =
    for {
      sequential = Schedule.recurs(10) andThen Schedule.spaced(1.second)
      _ <-  ZIO.effectTotal{ "hello" }.retry(sequential)
    } yield ()

}
```

I am getting this error:

> This error handling operation assumes your effect can fail. However,
> your effect has Nothing for the error type, which means it cannot
> fail, so there is no need to handle the failure. To find out which
> method you can use instead of this operation, please see the reference
> chart at: https://zio.dev/docs/can_fail [error]       _ <-
> ZIO.effectTotal{ "hello" }.retry(sequential)

I am returning a Task[String] which has a throwable error type.  If I replace effectTotal with effect then I don't get a compile error, but the program just exists without repeating the word hello even once.

What concept am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you can't have `=` in the first line of a for-comprehension. You need to wrap your pure value in `ZIO.succeed` or leave it outside the for-comprehension.

"Hello" is a pure string. You could use `ZIO.effectTotal` but technically it doesn't produce any side effect so you should also use `succeed` here.

`retry` retries on failure, but `effectTotal` / `succeed` cannot fail. You should be using `repeat` instead.

```scala
import zio._
import zio.duration._

object MyApp extends zio.App {
  def run(args: List[String]) =
    myAppLogic.exitCode

  val myAppLogic =
    for {
      sequential <- ZIO.succeed(Schedule.recurs(10) andThen Schedule.spaced(1.second))
      _ <-  ZIO.succeed("hello").repeat(sequential)
    } yield ()
}
```

Now with errors fixed it still doesn't display your texts because you are just producing values (not a side effect) without printing them (side effect).

The correct code should be something like:

```scala
import zio._
import zio.duration._
import zio.console._

object MyApp extends zio.App {
  def run(args: List[String]) =
    myAppLogic.exitCode

  //leave this out of the for-comprehension
  val sequential = Schedule.recurs(10) andThen Schedule.spaced(1.second)

  val myAppLogic = putStrLn("hello").repeat(sequential)

//  Or you could suspend the `println` side effect with `effectTotal` (doesn't fail but produces side effects)
//  val myAppLogicAlt = ZIO.effectTotal(println("hello")).repeat(sequential)
}
```

Comment: " However, succeed is intended for values which do not have any side effects. If you know that your value does have side effects consider using ZIO.effectTotal for clarity."..that's from the docs.  Is there a way to have it work using effectTotal also?

Comment: Which one are you talking about? The wrong code with the errors fixed or the bottom one that actually produces the result you want. Because I didn't use any `succeed` for the latter and I also provide you an alternative example that utilises `effectTotal` in the comments.

Comment: thanks for the clarification, appreciate it!